# Frame rate of h264 video?

Tags: video

How do I check the framerate of my .h264 video?
I used VLC player (tools) but it doesn't list the codec information as well as framerate.
I explicitly set the framerate to be 60.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are two complications with this:

- The h264 format doesn't include this information.
- The frame rate is not necessarily constant.

However, it can possibly be calculated by examining the file, and *supposedly* `avprobe` can do this:

```
> avprobe whatever.h264 
avprobe version 9.14-6:9.14-1rpi1rpi1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 22 2014 15:08:12 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
[h264 @ 0x39d0c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, h264, from 'whatever.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x360, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
                                                       ^^^^^^
```

*Unfortunately*, this was on a video I shot with `raspivid -fps 40`.  I guess the question is whether raspivid obeys the fps switch, or whether `avprobe` is correct.

On raspbian `avprobe` is in the `libav-tools`.

Comment: avprobe (and for that matter VLC) "guess" a framerate if the source file doesn't include one (like the H264 files output by raspivid and picamera). As we can see above, avprobe guesses 25 (which is a decent default) and I *think* VLC guesses 25 as well (though I haven't tested that). Raspivid (and picamera) do obey the framerate - you can see this more easily by selecting something like 90fps as the framerate (which will force VGA res) and playing it back in VLC - slow mo!

Comment: Can I count the total number of frames ? Even that information is not present in `.h264` ?

Comment: I presume you could scan the file for the total number of frames and their rate. Mp3 audio files have the same issue -- if they are not meta-tagged with a length (which they don't have to be), the only way to get the length is to guesstimate or (more accurately) scan the entire file.